# Converting DateTime from specific timezone to UTC - missing hour?

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone

I am having problem understanding how to convert `DateTime` to different timezones correctly.

Lets say, I want to convert `DateTime` with time: 10:00 (military) in EST to `DateTime` in UTC.

Here is what I try:

```
DateTime unspecified = new DateTime(2013, 8, 15, 10, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);
var utc = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(unspecified, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time"), TimeZoneInfo.Utc);
```

... I construct `DateTime` with `DateTimeKind.Unspecified`, because it's neither UTC, nor Local time (it is 10:00 EST). I then pass it to [TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb382770.aspx) telling that this is `DateTime` in EST and I want to convert it to UTC.

Since [EST is **5 hours** behind of Coordinated Universal Time (UTC)](http://www.timeanddate.com/library/abbreviations/timezones/na/est.html) I expect `utc` be equal to `{15.08.2013 15:00:00}`, however when I run code above I, for some reason, get `{15.08.2013 14:00:00}` (i.e. time difference is **4 hours**).

The question is: Why? Is this some kind of daytime saving time matter? If so - how to get this conversion without notion of daytime saving time?

Comment: Yes, daylight savings is the reason for this. A simple approach to not account for it would be to simply use the `BaseUtcOffset` of the `TimeZoneInfo`: `new DateTime(2013, 8, 15, 10, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Unspecified)
.Subtract(TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time").BaseUtcOffset);` However, I am not sure if that screws up in some special cases and which ones that could be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is a dalylight saving applied. See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Time_Zone)

> Places that use Eastern Standard Time (EST) when observing standard
>   time (autumn/winter) are **5 hours** behind Coordinated Universal Time
>   (UTC−05:00).
>
> Eastern Daylight Time (EDT), when observing daylight saving time
>   (spring/summer) is **4 hours** behind Coordinated Universal Time
>   (UTC−04:00).

The conversion method is correct. Your assumption about the EST timezone is flawed. If your input dates are really EST then the conversion is correct. If that does not meet your expectations you need to check from where your input data comes from and in which timezone it was really entered. 
If you are dealing with saved dates in a database and you do not know anymore what is correct and what not you are in trouble.

In general it is safer to use [DateTimeOffset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.datetimeoffset.aspx) instead of DateTime since it does store always UTC time as DateTime and the local timezone offset as an additional value inside it. That makes it trivial to determine from the local time the true UTC time.

Answer (score 1):

The Windows time zone that has the `Id` of `"Eastern Standard Time"` is not just for EST.  It covers both EST (-5) and EDT (-4).  You wouldn't  know it from the id name alone.  This is bit of naming anomaly is one of several screwy things with the Microsoft Windows time zone database.  See [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info) for more information.

Fortunately, it is not the only database around.  It isn't even the most commonly used database, it's just the default that ships with Windows and .Net.  To do this conversion with the standard IANA time zone database, use [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org):

```
DateTimeZone tz = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb["America/New_York"];
LocalDateTime dt = new LocalDateTime(2013, 8, 15, 10, 0, 0);
ZonedDateTime zdt = tz.AtLeniently(dt);
Instant utc = zdt.ToInstant();
```

Also notice how Noda Time gives you types that cannot be misinterpreted.  There is no `Kind` that affects behavior.  "Local" here just means *some* local value, not your own local clock.

Also notice that I apply the date to the time zone using `AtLeniently`.  This is a strategy that will make adjustments when ambiguous or invalid times are applied.  There is also `AtStrictly`, which will throw exceptions in those scenarios.  Or, you can create your own strategy.  The `TimeZoneInfo` class doesn't have this level of control.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert any DateTime of any TimeZone to UTCDateTime easily.

[Here is the Example](https://rextester.com/ING80333)

```
   string DisplayName = "custom standard name here";
   string StandardName = "custom standard name here"; 
   string YourDate="2013/8/15 10:0:0"; 
   TimeSpan Offset = new TimeSpan(+10, 00, 00);
   TimeZoneInfo TimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.CreateCustomTimeZone(StandardName, Offset, DisplayName, StandardName);
   var RawDateTime = DateTime.SpecifyKind(DateTime.Parse(YourDate), DateTimeKind.Unspecified);
   DateTime UTCDateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(RawDateTime, TimeZone);
   Console.WriteLine(UTCDateTime);
```